# Calling Two Methods To Return Different Pages In Java

Tags: java, spring, validation, if-statement

I have a method to check a users input is correct as card information & a method to return a error message (server side).

I want to return a payment successful page if all information is correct.
Return a payment failed page if the user input does not match the card information in a spreadsheet.    << Currently my program can do this.

If the user leaves a field blank i.e. card number I want it to return the same page with a validation message.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment-submission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePaymentSubmission(@ModelAttribute PaymentDetails paymentDetails, BindingResult resulttwo) {

if (payService.isPaymentDetailsCorrect(paymentDetails)) {
    return PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL;
}

return PAYMENT_FAILED;
```

This is my current code that works.

I am not sure how to call the method below which checks the validation into the above to make sure it returns the correct page.

```
private void validatePaymentDetails(final PaymentDetails paymentDetails, final BindingResult resulttwo) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(paymentDetails.getCardNumber())) {
        resulttwo.addError(new FieldError("paymentDetails", "cardNumber",
            "validate.payment-details-cardnumber.empty.message"));
        return;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in previous posts, I am new and learning JAVA so apologies if this is confusing or is incorrect.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using spring validator framework, you can achieve this.

1) Create a custom validator & implements Validator class like below.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class PaymentValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {

    return PaymentDetails.class.equals(paramClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object arg0, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "cardNumber", "error.cardNumber" , "Please give valid cardnumber");
}

}
```

2) In controller, Call this validate method and handle as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment-submission", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePaymentSubmission(@ModelAttribute PaymentDetails paymentDetails, BindingResult result) {

    paymentValidator.validate(paymentDetails, result);

    if( ! result.hasErrors()) {
    return PAYMENT_SUCCESSFUL;

    }

    return INPUT_PAGE;
}
```

3) In your jsp page, add this below element where you want to show the message

```
<form:errors path="cardNumber" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
```